contextBridge not exposing ipcRenderer to Vite dev server
I am developing an application with React Electron and Vite. I am trying to setup backend communication for Vite by using Electron's contextBridge.exposeToMainWorld in the preload.ts file. However, in the Vite dev server, I get a console error saying that ipcRenderer is undefined. It also seems that Vite is not loading the preload.ts file, despite it being correctly pathed in vite.config.ts in the preload.input value. I have searched a lot about this and: 1. I have found nothing similar, and 2. My implementation should already be working based on the docs I found. Can anyone give me ideas to fix this?
Btw: I have started this project by using the npm create electron-vite command.
